# programmatic way to stop a function after certain time and debug enclosed variables

Tags: debugging, timeout, scheme

A long-run function like infinite loop:

```
> (define appendInf
      (lambda (lst)
        (appendInf (cons 1 lst)))
```

In Chez Scheme, make-engine can achieve the stopping after ticks:

```
> (define eng
    (make-engine 
      (lambda ()
        (appendInf '()))))
```

While of course with the scope of lst I get error when:

```
> (eng 50
        list
        (lambda (new-eng)
          (set! eng new-eng)
          (length lst)))
Exception: variable lst is not bound
```

If I want to get the value 'lst' in appendInf when the time limit is reached, I use set!:

```
> (define lst '())
> (define appendInf
      (lambda (ls)
        (set! lst (cons 1 ls))
        (appendInf lst)))
```

now I can get:

```
> (eng 50
       list
       (lambda (new-eng)
         (set! eng new-eng)
         (length lst)))
8
```

So for every variable within the function I want to trace, a global variable needs to be added, and one more transforming by adding (set!…).

1. is this a correct way to handle any enclosed variables?
2. if yes to 1, in Scheme is there a better way to achieve this?
3. is there any programming language that can more easily
   implement this kind of debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Well. I'm using racket and it has a pretty good debugger and does standard r6rs as well as non-standard racket.

```
;; macro to do the heavy work
(define-syntax recdb
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ thunk fun a1 ...)
     (let ((orig-fun fun)(ethunk thunk))
       (fluid-let ((fun (lambda args 
                          (if (ethunk)
                              (apply orig-fun args) ;; set breakpoint on this
                              (apply orig-fun args)))))
         (fun a1 ...))))))

;; a time-thunk generator
(define (period-sec sec)
  (let ((time-done (+ sec (current-seconds))))
    (lambda ()
      (if (< time-done (current-seconds))
          (begin 
            (set! time-done (+ sec (current-seconds)))
            #t)
          #f))))

;; a round-thunk generator
(define (rounds n)
  (let ((rounds-to-go n))
    (lambda ()
      (if (zero? rounds-to-go)
          (begin
            (set! rounds-to-go (- n 1))
            #t)
          (begin
            (set! rounds-to-go (- rounds-to-go 1))
            #f)))))

;; my never ending procedure
(define (always n)
  (always (+ n 1)))

;; one of the ones below to implement 
(recdb (rounds 10) always 0))
(recdb (period-sec 1) always 0)

;; functions with auxillary procedures need to have their gut changed for it to work
(define (fib n)
  (define (fib-aux n a b)
    (if (= n 0)
        a
        (fib-aux (- n 1) b (+ a b))))
  (recdb (period-sec 2) fib-aux n 0 1))

 ;; trying it
 (fib 200000)
```

Now. Just run the debugger and set breakpoint (right click expression in the macro and choose "Pause at this point") where it's indicated in the code and you have a way to examine the variables every x seconds or x times.

Happy debugging :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for the laaate response. I tried to run it in DrRacket, but got 'fluid-let: unbound identifier in module'. Anyways, in your given case, my goal was to get the value of 'n' programmatically, without setting breakpoint in debugger and checking the variable manually.

Comment: @FromWhereToWhere `fluid-let` is defined in [SRFI-15](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-15/srfi-15.html). If you're using `#lang racket` you can replace `fluid-let` with [parameterize](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/parameters.html?q=parameterize#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/more-scheme..rkt%29._parameterize%29%29)